# Failed to load asset at "assets/dotenv.develop" in flutter web

Tags: flutter, pipeline, flutter-web

I am using `.env` file in flutter web.
Everything is OK when I run my project, locally on chrome and build apk.
But when I run my project in azure pipeline to deploy my flutter web, I get these errors:

```
GET https://***.net/assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf 404 (Not Found)

GET https://***.net/assets/.env.develop 404 (Not Found)
```

I tried running my project without .env file and everything was OK.

Also, I removed `dot` from the start of file name, from `".env"` to `"dotenv"`.
I added the file into the assets directory and include the file in the `pubspec.yaml`.
But didn't solve my issue.

Comment: After `flutter build web`, is your dotenv file copied to `build/web` folder within you project?

Comment: @PeterKoltai .env file copied to build/web/assets folder

Comment: As you wrote, file name should not begin with dot. If your deployment is created from `build/web`, it should contain your dotenv file. It could be a cache problem (try it from private browser mode, empty site cache etc.). Or maybe some file permission problem, check permissions.

Comment: @PeterKoltai When I rename to dotenv, error changes to GET https://***.net/assets/dotenv.develop 404 (Not Found). Then it is not a cache problem I think.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use .env as name for config file, use a name without "." Eg: dotenv

Here is the issue https://github.com/java-james/flutter_dotenv/issues/28

Comment: Thanks for your replying but I tired using dotenv instead of .env and unfortunately it is not working for me.